# Group 2d array by name

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

how to separate the data below into 3d array by the different English names.

#### The actual data

```
[['سمو', 'name']
 ['أله', 'name']
 ['حسن', 'name']
 ['قبس', 'brand']
 ['وسم', 'brand']]
```

#### The Expectation data

```
[[['سمو', 'name']
 ['أله', 'name']
 ['حسن', 'name']],
 [['قبس', 'brand']
 ['وسم', 'brand']]]
```

#### The code I have

```
old_data = [['سمو', 'name'],
            ['أله', 'name'],
            ['حسن', 'name'],
            ['قبس', 'brand'],
            ['وسم', 'brand']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools` can do this for you.

```
import itertools

grouped_data = itertools.groupby(old_data, lambda item: item[1])
```

[groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) returns an iterator rather than  a list; you can either loop through it, or flatten it like so:

```
flattened_groups = [list(group) for label, group in grouped_data]
```